# How to play alarm through headphones on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, headphones, alarm

Can an alarm sound in the headphone on iPhone, I don't care if it also sounds outside the headphones, but I think that having it come through the headphones would help me wake up, specifically wireless headphones

How can I get alarms play through headphones?

Answer (score 1):

By default the alarm goes through the headphones and the speakers if headphones are plugged in.